# How can I see the current line / column of the cursor in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: statusbar, visual-studio-2019

In earlier versions of Visual Studio the current line / column were displayed in the status bar.

In Visual Studio 2019 they've vanished.

Can anyone tell me how to find the line / column number of the cursor?

I'm hoping for a solution that will restore them to the status bar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The current line / column are now displayed in the bottom right of the editor window.

Comment: Perhaps they are for you, but not for me. Anyone have an answer the explains when these are displayed, or what settings should be on?

Comment: @ZephaniahGrunschlag They also need to be enabled in VS Options - Text Editor - Show editing context in the editor.

Comment: Thanks. I was being silly, but still this is annoying.  It depends on how large my editor window is. When I'm editing on my 13" laptop screen, there isn't enough room on the bottom strip to show the line/column numbers with all the other widgets (git branch, python virtual env, .... is what I'm calling "widgets"). When I connect the laptop to my larger monitor, sure enough, I can see the line numbers. I wonder if there is a way to prioritize line/column number over other widgets?

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>(mentioned by @sergey-vlasov, but adding details)</sub>*

You can turn this on in the Options menu.  It appears to be disabled by default.

Do this,

1. Go into the "Tools | Options" menu,
2. Select "Text Editor" and view the General-options,
3. Find and Enable the "Show editing context in the editor" box.
   [image: Text Editor Options]

Once enabled, the Ln and Ch values will be displayed at the bottom-right of the file you're editing.